# Many-to-Many Relationships in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Consider this Many-to-Many relationships table.

```
content_tag = Table('content_tag', db.metadata,
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('content_id', Integer, ForeignKey('content.id'), primary_key=True)
)
```

How do I write a query to calculate the amount of all such records with a specific tag_id?
Or how to update all records with key tag_id?

The common syntax is not working.